# What is Node in haskell?

Tags: haskell, data-structures, nodes

What exactly is Node? is it a keyword? a data type? I can't figure out how it works.

If if define this, for example

```
data Seq a = Empty | Node a (Seq a)
```

Am I saying there is a variable a with the type Node, am I defining a new type, what is it exactly?

Comment: `Node` is a *data constructor*.

Comment: Another way of writing this is with the `GADTSyntax` language flag: `data Seq a where { Empty :: Seq a; Node :: a -> Seq a -> Seq a }`. While this is more verbose, I feel it’s also clearer that the statement *defines* `Empty` and `Node` as the data constructors of `Seq`, and explicitly shows their type signatures.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the comment states, `Node` is a data constructor. This means it's a possible way of constructing a value of type `Seq a` (where `a` represents another type).

This particular data structure represents a sequence, which can be constructed either using the `Empty` data constructor or with the `Node` one.

For example:

```hs
empty :: Seq a
empty = Empty

seqOf1Int :: Seq Int
seqOf1Int = Node 5 Empty

seqOf2Strings :: Seq String
seqOf2Strings = Node "hello" (Node "world" Empty)
```

Answer (score 5):

In this case, `Empty` and `Node` are [*data constructors* [Haskell wiki]](https://wiki.haskell.org/Constructor#Data_constructor). Each value with type `Seq a` is either an `Empty`, or a `Node` that wraps two parameters: the first one of type `a`, and the other one a `Seq a` value.

One can thus construct values with arbitrary size in this case, for example `Empty`, `Node 1 Empty`, `Node 1 (Node 4 Empty)`, etc. Therefore you definition looks like the definition of a list `[]`, which is implemented as a linked list in Haskell.

You can use data constructors as functions where they take parameters for the parameters, so `Node` can be used as a function `Node :: a -> Seq a -> Seq a`.

Data constructors are also used to pattern match. For example you can implement a function:

```
seqSize :: Seq a -> Int
seqSize Empty = 0
seqSize (Node _ xs) = 1 + seqSize xs
```

here it will thus pattern match and in case the value is an `Empty` it will return zero. For a `Node` the variable `xs` refers to the second parameter of the value (so also of type `Seq a`) that can then be used in the recursive call.

Answer (score 4):

In general, `Node` is an identifier starting with a capital letter, which means that it's a valid name for type and data constructors.

In this specific code you're defining it as a data constructor that takes two arguments of types `a` and `Seq a` respectively and which belongs to the type `Seq a`.

Answer (score 2):

```hs
data Seq a = Empty | Node a (Seq a)
```

is a data type definition where `Seq a` is the type and `Empty` and `Node a (Seq a)` are its constructors.

`Node` is a recursive constructor. It has a value of type `a` that it receives as a parameter on construction. The second parameter to `Node` is of type `Seq a` which is the type of `Node` itself, thus it becomes a recursive data structure. `Seq a` that is passed as a parameter to `Node` can be constructed with any of `Seq`s constructors, namely `Empty` and `Node`. `Empty` closes the recursive data structure as it doesn't receive itself any new parameters of type `Seq a`.